# Advanced RAM configuration

Tags: memory, performance, default-settings, performance-tuning

I'm a little unsure about whether my current BIOS ram settings are the optimal for the RAM i have. I'm aware some RAM modules may configure themselves with a bit slower speed by default than what they are actually rated for.

I have a Ripjaws kit called **F3-17000CL9Q-16GBZH** and an **ASUS P8Z77-V PRO** mainboard.

The question is: Judging by the information under "Memory" near the top of the image, do i have the optimal DRAM frequency and timings for this RAM, or should i set some other values manually?

[image: Here are my current settings from Speccy]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated to be a bit clearer, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JEDEC information tags are manufacturer tags included on the memory to signal what the safe-tested settings are for each frequency listed. The top portion is the current setting. If you cross-reference the the tag list with the settings, you'll see that "yes" they are what the manufacturer says are the correct numbers, or almost nearly so.

Can you trust the manufacturer? no idea.

Does it matter that much? In a synthetic test probably, in the real world, probably not. If you aren't crashing, don't worry. In my personal experience, you will have more problems with mis-matched sets of RAM and the BIOS auto-selecting for the faster set. The solution is to set the latencies manually to the slower set.

Comment: TLDR: Is it broke? Then your settings are correct.

Comment: @surfasb: +1 (yeah)

Answer (score 1):

Your current RAS# to CAS# timing are a bit too fast. According to the SPD data from the RAM it should be 12, you use 11. Also tRAS should be 30 instead of 28. Both wrong data can cause some errors (BSOD for example).